# Looping through awk output

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, bioinformatics

I have a series of strings. These are composed of smaller strings labeled as 'nodes', sometimes on their own, sometimes connected by characters `:` or `,`.

I'd like to split the larger strings ('headers') into 'nodes'.

I've managed to remove some extra characters (`>`, `;`, `'`) with sed, and I'm using awk to split the remaining strings on `:` and `,`

The issue is that I'd like to loop through the output (the 'nodes'), not only the first awk column. I've tried using `{print $0}` for awk, but that just printed out the initial strings with delimiters and all.

Please help?

Example input (dealt with by a for loop in the sample, in the larger code it's an output of an if/else):

```
>NODE_3028138_length_2215_cov_1.9513_ID_6056275:NODE_6264558_length_375_cov_4.0000_ID_12529115';
>NODE_4338305_length_1150_cov_1.0000_ID_8676609;
>NODE_3552704_length_509_cov_1.0000_ID_7105407:NODE_4456634_length_439_cov_1.9597_ID_8913267',NODE_4457268_length_491_cov_0.9657_ID_8914535';
```

Example output (without node NODE_4338305 because it's on its own):

```
NODE_3028138_length_2215_cov_1.9513_ID_6056275
NODE_6264558_length_375_cov_4.0000_ID_12529115
NODE_3552704_length_509_cov_1.0000_ID_7105407
NODE_4456634_length_439_cov_1.9597_ID_8913267
NODE_4457268_length_491_cov_0.9657_ID_8914535
```

Ideally I would want to loop through each of the entries above (`NODE_3028138_length_2215_cov_1.9513_ID_6056275`, then `NODE_6264558_length_375_cov_4.0000_ID_12529115` etc)

```
for i in ">NODE_3028138_length_2215_cov_1.9513_ID_6056275:NODE_6264558_length_375_cov_4.0000_ID_12529115';" \
">NODE_4338305_length_1150_cov_1.0000_ID_8676609;" \
">NODE_3552704_length_509_cov_1.0000_ID_7105407:NODE_4456634_length_439_cov_1.9597_ID_8913267',NODE_4457268_length_491_cov_0.9657_ID_8914535';"
do      
if [[ $i == *":"* ]];         
then 
echo $i            
i=$(sed "s/[>;\']//g" <<< $i);            
echo $i
echo $i | awk -F '[:,]' '{print $1}' | while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$line"; done
fi; done
```

Edit to add operating system information:

- Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
- Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-1127.el7.x86_64
- Architecture: x86-64

Comment: To loop through fields in awk: `{for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {print $i}}`. But it is unclear to me if this is the answer to your question.

Comment: Since you're already using `sed`, why not add a second expression that replaces all `[:,]` with newlines to that?

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you! The idea sounds very intuitive, but I've tried 'i=$(sed "s/[:,]/\n/g" <<< $i)' and only got spaces, not new lines, and I also tried 'i=$(sed "s/[:,]/\r/g" <<< $i)' and...I only got the last node, so I'm not sure what went wrong.

Comment: @guest Thank you, this works well!

Comment: I wouldn't bother with the `$(...)` command substitution - you could just do something like `printf '%s\n' "$i" | sed -e "s/[>;\']//g" -e "s/[:,]/\n/g"`

Comment: I have improved the formatting. Check whether I have understood the meaning of the brackets after "I've managed to remove some extra characters" correctly.

Comment: @Laura please [edit] your question and tell us what operating system you are using. Your comment about `sed` suggests you are not using GNU `sed`. Also, please clarify what you want to loop over because it isn't clear at all. If you already have `awk` there why would you want a shell loop at all? Just show us your input, and your desired output. We should be able to give you a far simpler approach than what you're using.

Comment: @terdon Thank you, edited!

Comment: @Laura so at the beginning you start with a collection of fasta files, right?

Comment: @terdon fastg. Which is fasta but with information in the header about how the contigs are connected. I have a set of contigs of interest and I'd like to see if they are connected to each other (maybe even with some contigs-of-less-interest inbetween). So I thought...Start by grepping my sequences of interest, recover the headers, separate headers into nodes, grep the fastg file again to recover all headers with the same nodes, check if I already have the headers (do nothing) or not (add them to headers file. separate into nodes. check if nodes are present in nodes file. If no, add). Repeat.

Comment: Sounds like you want (assuming your sequences of interest are in `seqs.txt`): `grep -Ff seqs.txt *fastg | sed -n '/^>/{s/>//; s/[,:]/\n/gp}' *.fasta | tr -d "';" > wanted.nodes; grep -wFf wanted.nodes all.nodes`. Feel free to ping me in [/dev/chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat) if you want help. Also, you might be interested in our sister site, [bioinformatics.se] where us bioinformatician types hang out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need any of the steps you show. If I understand correctly, you start with a collection of fasta files, a format that looks like this:

```
>header
sequence
```

And you want to extract the headers, remove the `>` and any `'` and split them on `,` or `;`. If so, you can do this directly on the fasta files themselves:

```
$ sed -n '/^>/{s/>//; s/[,:]/\n/gp}' *.fasta | tr -d "';"
NODE_3028138_length_2215_cov_1.9513_ID_6056275
NODE_6264558_length_375_cov_4.0000_ID_12529115
NODE_3552704_length_509_cov_1.0000_ID_7105407
NODE_4456634_length_439_cov_1.9597_ID_8913267
NODE_4457268_length_491_cov_0.9657_ID_8914535
```

#### Explanation

- `sed -n`: suppress normal output, don't print anything unless explicitly told to.
- `/^>/{something}`: if this line starts with a `>`, do `something`.
- `s/^>//;`: remove the `>` from the beginning of the line.
- `s/[,:]/\n/gp` : replace all (all because of the `g` at the end) `,` or `:` with a newline (`\n`) and then print (you print because of the `p` at the end.
- `tr -d "';"`: delete any `;` or `'`.

In your comment, you said you tried `'i=$(sed "s/[:,]/\n/g" <<< $i)'` and only got spaces, not newlines. That's because you then ran `echo $i` instead of `echo "$i"`, so the newlines were lost.

---

If you really do need to do this on the collection of strings you show, you can do:

```
for i in ">NODE_3028138_length_2215_cov_1.9513_ID_6056275:NODE_6264558_length_375_cov_4.0000_ID_12529115';" ">NODE_4338305_length_1150_cov_1.0000_ID_8676609;" ">NODE_3552704_length_509_cov_1.0000_ID_7105407:NODE_4456634_length_439_cov_1.9597_ID_8913267',NODE_4457268_length_491_cov_0.9657_ID_8914535';"; do 
    sed -n '/^>/{s/>//; s/[,:]/\n/gp}' <<<"$i" | tr -d "';" ; 
done
NODE_3028138_length_2215_cov_1.9513_ID_6056275
NODE_6264558_length_375_cov_4.0000_ID_12529115
NODE_3552704_length_509_cov_1.0000_ID_7105407
NODE_4456634_length_439_cov_1.9597_ID_8913267
NODE_4457268_length_491_cov_0.9657_ID_8914535
```

Answer (score 2):

The following solution is somewhat crude, but should work. It is assumed that, as you show in your sample input, all nodes begin with the string `NODE` (if that is not the case, you need to provide a more complete input example).

Assuming your strings are, in fact, in a file `input.txt`, the following `awk` call will do the trick:

```
awk '{gsub(/[:>,;\047]/,""); n=split($0,a,/NODE/); for (i=2;i<=n;i++) printf("NODE%s\n",a[i])}' input.txt
```

- This will first replace all "extra" characters using `gsub()` (`\047` is the single quote `'` which can't be placed verbatim on the command-line as the `awk` commands themselves are inside single-quotes).
- Then, it will split the remaining string into fields at the pattern `NODE`, and store the result in the array `a`.
- Any "field", except for the very first (which would be the string before the first occurence of `NODE`) is then printed separately, with `NODE` being prepended.

For your example input the result is:

```
awk '{gsub(/[:>,;\047]/,""); n=split($0,a,/NODE/); for (i=2;i<=n;i++) printf("NODE%s\n",a[i])}' input.txt
NODE_3028138_length_2215_cov_1.9513_ID_6056275
NODE_6264558_length_375_cov_4.0000_ID_12529115
NODE_4338305_length_1150_cov_1.0000_ID_8676609
NODE_3552704_length_509_cov_1.0000_ID_7105407
NODE_4456634_length_439_cov_1.9597_ID_8913267
NODE_4457268_length_491_cov_0.9657_ID_8914535
```

If you want to skip lines that only contain one such "node", the command can be modified as:

```
awk '{gsub(/[:>,;\047]/,""); if ((n=split($0,a,/NODE/))<3) next; for (i=2;i<=n;i++) printf("NODE%s\n",a[i])}' input.txt
NODE_3028138_length_2215_cov_1.9513_ID_6056275
NODE_6264558_length_375_cov_4.0000_ID_12529115
NODE_3552704_length_509_cov_1.0000_ID_7105407
NODE_4456634_length_439_cov_1.9597_ID_8913267
NODE_4457268_length_491_cov_0.9657_ID_8914535
```

Comment: @EdMorton good point; included!

Answer (score 0):

Tried with below python method

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
m=re.compile(r'[:;,]')
k=open('filename','r')
for i in k:
    co=i.count("NODE")
    if co > 1:
        q=i.strip()
        k=re.sub(m,"\n",q)
        print k.strip().replace("'","").replace(">","")
```

output

```
NODE_3028138_length_2215_cov_1.9513_ID_6056275
NODE_6264558_length_375_cov_4.0000_ID_12529115
NODE_3552704_length_509_cov_1.0000_ID_7105407
NODE_4456634_length_439_cov_1.9597_ID_8913267
NODE_4457268_length_491_cov_0.9657_ID_8914535
```

awk: Already best solution provided in awk its just my try

```
awk '{print $0,gsub("NODE",$0)}' filename| awk '$NF >1 {print $1}'| sed "s/[;:,]/\n/g"|sed '/^$/d'| sed "s/[\>']//g"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `gawk` and don't mind a leading blank line then you can

- compose `RS` to consume `'*;\n` which cleans up the end of each line
- compose `FS` to consume combinations of `[>;,']+`
- compose `OFS` to provide `\n` and
- set `ORS` to empty.

This means that the empty `$1` (the field before `>`) gives you a `\n` between records if you recompose `$0` on `OFS` with `$1=$1`. Other than that just `print` wherever you have `NF>2`

```
awk -F"[>:,']+" -v OFS="\n" -v RS="'*;\n" -v ORS="" 'NF>2{$1=$1; print }END{print "\n"}' file

NODE_3028138_length_2215_cov_1.9513_ID_6056275
NODE_6264558_length_375_cov_4.0000_ID_12529115
NODE_3552704_length_509_cov_1.0000_ID_7105407
NODE_4456634_length_439_cov_1.9597_ID_8913267
NODE_4457268_length_491_cov_0.9657_ID_8914535
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `sed` editor we can generate the desired output as follows.

```
sed \
  -e '/\n/{/^\n/!P;D;}'                    \
  -e "/^>NODE_.*NODE/ y/>;:,'/\n\n\n\n\n/" \
  -e '/\n/G;D'                             \
file
```

**Results:**

```
NODE_3028138_length_2215_cov_1.9513_ID_6056275
NODE_6264558_length_375_cov_4.0000_ID_12529115
NODE_3552704_length_509_cov_1.0000_ID_7105407
NODE_4456634_length_439_cov_1.9597_ID_8913267
NODE_4457268_length_491_cov_0.9657_ID_8914535
```

**Working method:**

- Only  lines that comprise atleast two NODEs plus they begin with `>NODE_`
  Let’s call them "interesting" lines. We change each occurrence of `>;:,'` to a newline each in the interesting lines.
- Then append a newline to the interesting lines just in case it didn't end with a semicolon. The `D` command shall initiate an implicit looping and take us to the first line of sed code.
- The first line is where all the action happens and the interesting line is consumed fully while sed belts out the NODEs serially, one per line.